# Spring boot: CsvReader class not reading filename from application.properties correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, controller

Good evening good programmers,
I am new to Spring Boot and do not see what I am doing wrong in the following set up.

The application.properties has
io.input_file = "C:\Projects\validation\validation_input.csv"

ApplicationController.java reads the io.input_file into inputFilename field and outputs it correctly.
I see the filename displayed on the /parameters webpage correctly

ValidationApplication.java's main() calls List inputRows = new CsvReader().read();
The OpenCSV reader and writer find and process the CSV file contents correctly.

My problem is CsvReader.java has C:\Projects\validation\validation_input.csv filename hard-coded.
I want to replace the hardcoded filename with the ValidationController.inputFilename
It is always null!

What am I not understanding or missing?
Thank you in advance,
E-men

application.properties file:

```
endpoint.url = "http://192.168.7.180:7150/api/latest/ngene/search"
io.input_file = "C:\\Projects\\validation\\validation_input.csv"  
io.output_file = "C:\\Projects\\validation\\validation_output.csv"
io.output_file_stats = "C:\\Projects\\validation\\validation_outputStats.csv" 



// ValidationController.java
@RestController
public class ValidationController {
    // Inject parameters from application.properties or application.yml: default if N/A
    @Value("${endpoint.url: Endpoint URL: TBD}")
    private String endpointURL;              // URL can be tracked outside on confluence page

    @Value("${io.input_file: input_file default path}")
    private String inputFilename;

    @GetMapping("/parameters")
    public String readParameters() {
        String output = "<b>Testing default localhost:8080/parameters</b>";
        output += "<p>End point URL = " + endpointURL + "</p>";
        output += "<p>Input file = " + inputFilename + "</p>";
        return output;
    }
}

// ValidationApplication.java:
@SpringBootApplication
public class ValidationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, CsvDataTypeMismatchException, CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException {
        SpringApplication.run(ValidationApplication.class, args);

        // Lambda to print all
        System.out.println("\n\n\nLambda printing of CSV data read in:");
        List<InputData> inputRows = new CsvReader().read();
        inputRows.forEach(inputData -> System.out.println("\t" + inputData));

        List<OutputData> outputRows = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("\n\n\nValidationApplication::main(): reading, validating, and writing of CSV data:");
        // Read each row, process, write out
        for (int i = 0; i<inputRows.size(); i++) {
            // Read row data
            InputData inputData = inputRows.get(i);
            System.out.println("\t" + i + ": " + inputData.toString());

            // Validate data
            System.out.println("\tValidate data here...");

            // Write row data
            String moreData = inputData.getData();
            OutputData outputData = new OutputData(moreData);
            System.out.println("\t" + i + ": " + outputData.toString() + "\n");
            outputRows.add(outputData);
        }

        // Test the manual CSV writer with headers
        CsvWriter csvWriter = new CsvWriter();

        // Test the bean CSV writer without headers
        csvWriter.write(outputRows);
    }
}



// CsvReader.java:
public class CsvReader {
    public List<InputData> read() throws FileNotFoundException {

        // Get input filename
        String inputFile = "C:\\Projects\\validation\\validation_input.csv";

        // Create the CSV reader
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);

        CsvToBean<InputData> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<InputData>(fileReader)
                .withType(InputData.class)
                .build();

        // Read/parse and close reader streams
        return csvToBean.parse();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us how do you give ValidationController.inputFilename to CsvReader.

Comment: I am having trouble getting ValidationController.inputFilename in the main(). When I get that, I will pass it to the constructor i.e. CsvReader(ValidationController.getInputFilename ()). It's the annotations and order of events that's challenging me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either bring the CSVReader into spring. In this case, you can annotate CSVReader as a component and inject inputFilename into it, and use it.

Or, you can pass inputFilename to CSVReader via constructor and use it there.

```
    public class CsvReader {
        String inputFile ;
        public CsvReader(String inputFile ){
            this.inputFile =inputFile ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Niyas. I am annotating CsvReader, & attempting field injection, & failing! What am I missing?

@Component
public class CsvReader {

    @Value("${io.input_file: default input file}")
    private String inputFile;

    public CsvReader() {
    }

    public List<InputData> read() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String inputFile = this.inputFile; // Is null
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);

        CsvToBean<InputData> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder...

        return csvToBean.parse();
    }
}

Comment: Are you autowiring the CSVReader in ValidationController? Did spring inject the object of CSVReader?

Comment: Good morning and yes, Niyas. I was missing @Controller annotation i 1 or 2 spots. I added those, got the filename in the main, and setting it from there. I could not make the constructor with the filename passed work, but then again, that's the joy of learning new jazz. I will figure that out too. THANKS A MIL for your input, follow up, and care :).

Answer (score 0):

I was missing @Controller annotation in 1 or 2 spots. I added those, got the filename in the main, and set it from there.

I could not make the constructor with the filename passed work, but then again, that's the joy of learning new jazz. I will figure that out too.

Thanks A MIL for Niyas's input, it pointed me in the right dir to get the answer.